# How to clear part of the canvas using strokeStyle?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

My problem is following:

I have an  and it does have transparent background. It is used as drawing board over other elements. Once something is drawn, I would like to be able to erase it using eraser tool, which will have kind of same functionality as drawing tool.

One option is using clearRect and cleaning small rect on dragging. Is there any more brilliant solution? Perhaps something simple what involves strokeStyle?

Answer (score 0):

What if, for your eraser tool, you set strokeStyle to rgba(255,255,255,0), thereby filling any canvas pixels involved in the stroke with transparent white, essentially 'clearing' them?

Answer (score 0):

Try drawing with the context property "globalCompositeOperation" set to "destination-out".  Does that work with all browsers which support Canvas?